# How to find a dynamic text in text file

Tags: c#, text

Sorry for the weird question as I don't know what to put in it.

I am working on a text file, want to know the value next to that string like:

> ItemIndex = 6; //the number 6 will change overtime

So I want to get that value "6" and change that, here's my code:

```
var textSample= File.ReadAllText(path to text file);
var textConfig = textSample.Replace("ItemIndex =\"0\"", "ItemIndex =\"$$$\"");
var changedConfig = textConfig.Replace("ItemIndex =\"$$$\"", $"ItemIndex =\"{myValue}\"");
File.WriteAllText(path to text file, changedConfig);
```

But that no work. Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by 'not working'? What are you expecting to happen, and what actually happens?

Comment: I expected the ItemIndex = 6 to be changed to ItemIndex = {myValue}, the code run fine, except that value didn't change.

Comment: Is the `0` a typo?

Comment: For me it seems like you're trying to create a config file. If that's the case I would recommend to create a config class. You can read and write this class to a config file, by using the XmlSerializer.

Comment: Where did you expect it to change? In the file? Or inside the variable `changedConfig`?

Comment: you can use Regular Expressions: `var changedConfig = Regex.Replace(textSample, "ItemIndex = \d", $"ItemIndex = {myValue}");`

Comment: well sorry, that's why i'm asking for help, because i want to know how to get that value "6", and that "6" wont stay same forever because it keeps updating.

Comment: Try [`Regex.Replace(String, String)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=net-5.0#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex_Replace_System_String_System_String_)? `Regex reg = new Regex("ItemIndex = (.+);");`

Comment: thanks guys! The Regular Expressions solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

I don't get why you are converting from 0 to '$$$', then from '$$$' to myValue. Your code works, maybe it's a silly error like not checking that white spaces in the string match the ones in the file.